# Some lines of code in Jupyter notebook become too slow

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I always run code on Jupyter, and everything is good, but recently it takes a lot of time to execute some code, as example :

```
corr = train.corr()
highest_corr = corr[corr.index[abs(corr["claim"])>0.006]]
```

or even just :

```
train = pd.read_csv('Desktop\\train.csv')
```

So what is the problem? and how to solve it?

PS: I saw in another place that I should not use large values for :

```
pd.set_option('display.max_column', 120)
```

So I removed it, but it remains the same problem.

Comment: Well, what is the size of the CSV or the `train` dataframe?

Comment: The train dataframe has 957919 rows and 120 columns.

Comment: There's not really enough detail to provide here. If you are running more external processes, have some malware on your system, haven't cleared your Notebook kernel, or have a larger file in general, then yeah, your code will run slower...